# Autorotation in multi window in iOS

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm building a library in which I'm creating a window and then attaching my own view controller (subclass of UIViewController class) to it. Now I need to use it in a test application. Now when I'm trying to rotate this screen on changing the orientation, it is not happening as my own view controller is not getting the shouldAutoRotateOnOrientaionChange notification. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Supported Device Orientations` in the `Summary` tab of your target's settings.

Comment: In which project, library project or application project and how to do it in xCode version 3.2

Comment: how to do this programmatically?

Comment: No you can't you need to specify the supported orientations of the application. You can also do it in your appname-info.plist file.

Comment: In Static library project, I dont have any info.plist file

Comment: Actually I want to have orientation change control with my library. So how can I get the orientation change notification in my view controller?  and thnks for helping me.

Comment: Do you have more than one views added to your window in applicationDidFinishLaunching: ? That could cause the shouldAutoRotateOnOrientaionChange method not being called on your view controller. You should have only one controller's view added to the main window...

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1688.html

Comment: Hi, I need to build the library that need to be shipped outside the organization and it will be consumed by outside developer, and in my library I m having my own window and my own view controller(subclass of UIViewController), now when device is rotating , the orientation change notification is sent to the view controller of the application. I just want to intercept this notification in my library's view controller. Can I do that?